# issues with !important (i think)

Tags: css

Basically,

```
inside a div i have 2 divs
div #1 has an img inside
div #2 has text and a list inside
```

The outer div has a padding, the first div containing the image has a float left and top margin, the second div containing the text and list has a float right and top margin

Their sizes are set in percentages, then I also have a @media query which checks for max-width and max-height.

If the browser is resized under a certain amount of pixels in height or width some of the margins and widths/heights change and the div containing the image goes in the middle and the other div containing the text and list goes in the middle under the div containing the image.

NOW-----

I used !important for some of the css codes inside the media query and for some reason the div contaning the image and the div containing the text and list are stuck in the middle, image up top and text with list under...

I took the !important out of the media query and they are still stuck...

They're stuck like this(the media query output):

```
__________
|        |
|        |
|________|
__________
|        |
|        |
|________|
```

When they are meant to be like this(normal css output):

```
__________       __________
|        |       |        |
|        |       |        |
|________|       |________|
```

[jsFiddle Link <<<<](https://jsfiddle.net/xxp1obzq/)

Now what's weird is I tried to reproduce the error in jsFiddle by writing the code again but this time just for the image and text and I'm not getting the same issue...

[sample error](https://jsfiddle.net/a416rzse/)

Comment: It would be **a lot better** if you created a [mcve] of your issue, rather storytelling it. Code is code and, most times, the ones asking questions are missing information in regard to what it does. Please reproduce your problem in a snippet/fiddle.

Comment: Try to paste your current code in an online editor as http://http://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can understand what you're explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under this section in your css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px),
screen and (max-height: 875px) {
........
........
```

You have not set the divs to display:inline-block and also the width your relative for your info div with id `#web-adv-info` is 100%

this portion I made some adjustment

```
 #big-icon-wrapper {
    width: 39.6%;
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 2vh auto 0;
  }
  #web-adv-info {
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2vh 0;
  }
```

fiddle here

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: lightgrey;
}

body {
  width: calc(100% - 1vw);
  height: calc(100% - 1vh);
  padding: 0.5vh 0.5vw;
}


/*outer shell*/

#top-bar,
nav,
#footer {
  background: aliceblue;
}


/*main shell*/

#outer-body-wrapper {
  background: aliceblue;
}

#top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2.563em;
  height: 8%;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#top-bar > img {
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
  float: left;
}

#top-bar-options {
  border-left: 4px dashed lightgrey;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
}

#top-bar-options > a {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5px auto 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#fc {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  min-width: 75px;
}

#fc > span {
  font-size: 40px;
  min-font-size: 20px;
  bottom: -9px;
  float: left;
  color: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#outer-body-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  height: calc(76% + 6px);
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 12px auto 0;
}

#body-title {
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  height: 10%;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#inner-body-wrapper {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 66%;
  float: left;
}

#big-icon-wrapper {
  width: 55%;
  float: left;
  margin: 3vh 0 0;
}

#big-icon-wrapper > img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#big-icon-wrapper{
  border:solid 
}

#web-adv-info {
  background: orange;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 15vh 0 0;
  display:inline-block;
  border:solid red;
}

#web-adv-info > ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 2.4vw;
}

#under-inner-body-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(12% - 1vh);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1vh 0 0;
  float: left;
}

#banner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12%;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#c-right {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 60%;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

#c-assistance {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 75px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

#c-assistance > a {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 52%;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#c-assistance > a:first-child {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}

nav {
  margin: 3px auto 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30px;
}

nav > ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  margin: 0;
}


/*nav > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
    background: black;
}
nav > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
    background:blue;
}
nav > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
    background: yellow;
}*/

nav > ul > li {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav > ul > li > a:hover {
  background: lightgrey;
  color: aliceblue;
}

nav,
nav > ul,
nav > ul > li:first-child,
nav > ul > li > a {
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

nav,
nav > ul,
nav > ul > li:first-child,
nav > ul > li > a {
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px),
screen and (max-height: 875px) {
  nav {
    width: 90%;
  }
  #outer-body-wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    height: calc(76% - 10px);
  }
  #body-title {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  #inner-body-wrapper {
    padding: 0 10%;
    width: 80%;
  }
  #big-icon-wrapper {
    width: 39.6%;
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 2vh auto 0;
  }
  #web-adv-info {
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2vh 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 490px),
screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  #top-bar > img {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
  }
  nav,
  nav > ul,
  nav > ul > li:first-child,
  nav > ul > li > a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  nav,
  nav > ul,
  nav > ul > li:first-child,
  nav > ul > li > a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  #outer-body-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(76% - 38px);
  }
  #c-right {
    width: 65%;
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }
  #footer {
    min-height: 0;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <?php require_once("scripts/checkBrowser.php"); ?>
    <script>
      document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')

    </script>
    <div id="top-bar">
      <img src="css/images/mini-fc-icon.png" alt="mini-logo" />
      <div id="top-bar-options">
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
        <a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a>
        <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
      </div>
      <div id="fc"><span><b>FC</b></span></div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="subscribe.php">Subscribe</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About us!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="outer-body-wrapper">
      <div id="body-title">
        <b>Wecome to FusionCube!</b>
      </div>
      <div id="inner-body-wrapper" style="padding: 0 20%; width: 60%;">
        <div id="big-icon-wrapper"><img src="css/images/large-fc-icon.png" /></div>
        <div id="web-adv-info">
          Why FusionCube?
          <br/> here's a short list to why:
          <ul>
            <li>reason 1</li>
            <li>reason 2</li>
            <li>reason 3</li>
            <li>reason 4</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="under-inner-body-wrapper">
        register now!
        <br/> already have an account? Log in
      </div>
      <div id="banner">banner</div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div id="c-right">Sebastian Marian Zdroana
        <br> csd2550
        <br> M00495434 - Middlesex University</div>
      <div id="c-assistance">
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        <br>
        <a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you very much, need to get my head around display, position, floats, I know what they do it's just when you have too much code it's so easy to forget where everything is and how to sort problems.

Comment: @SebastianZdroana..that so true..:D